# Get Youtube title using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I am trying to use C# selenium to get a youtube video title. These won't work. I already tried getting .Text from other elements and they work fine. So I narrowed down to these lines which I think is problematic. Help is very much appreciated. Will love to know where I went wrong.

```
var title = driver.FindElement(By.Id("title")).FindElement(By.ClassName("style-scope ytd-watch-metadata")).Text;
```

```
var title = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("h1.title yt-formatted-string")).Text;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your locators are not unique.
Try this:

```cs
var title = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#info-contents h1.title yt-formatted-string")).Text;
```

Also `style-scope ytd-watch-metadata` are actually 2 class names: `style-scope` and `ytd-watch-metadata` while `By.ClassName` accepts single class name parameter. For multiple class names use XPath or CSS Selectors.
Also don't forget to add delays, preferably `WebDriverWait` expected conditions explicit waits.

Comment: Thank you! Your line worked. I also took your advice and put in: driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

Comment: I talked about `WebDriverWait` expected conditions explicit waits, not `ImplicitWait`. These are different tools while `WebDriverWait` is preferred in most cases. Also, don't use both `WebDriverWait` and `ImplicitWait` in the same class, this may cause problems.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help and guidance. Will take note on the difference.

Comment: You are more than welcome, my friend